# How to understand `defer` in go language?

Tags: go

In the godoc(https://blog.golang.org/defer-panic-and-recover), there is an example:

> 3. Deferred functions may read and assign to the returning function's named return values.
>
> In this example, a deferred function increments the return value i
>   after the surrounding function returns. Thus, this function returns 2:

```
func c() (i int) {
    defer func() { i++ }()
    return i
}
```

I also wrote a small progam:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func b() int {
    i := 0
    for ; i < 4; i++ {
        defer func() {fmt.Println(i); i++} ()
    }
    return i
}
func main() {
  fmt.Println("result = ", b())
}
```

the output is:

```
4
5
6
7
result =  4
```

So I am confused, why does the second example not output `8` ?

Comment: Check out, may help: https://blog.learngoprogramming.com/golang-defer-simplified-77d3b2b817ff

Answer (score 10):

Note the part that says "may read and assign to the returning function's **named return values**."

This means that:

```
func b() int {
    var i int
    defer func() { fmt.Println(i); i++ }()
    return i
}
```

will say `0` and `result = 0`, while:

```
func b() (i int) {
    defer func() { fmt.Println(i); i++ }()
    return i
}
```

will say `0` and `result = 1`.

It might help to imagine that the `return i` in my first example assigns the `i` value to a hidden return variable (because it's not named), then goes on to execute the `defer` statements (which only modify the local variable `i`), while in the second example we assign directly to the return variable (because it's named) and so the `defer` statement is able to change it.

Basically your program could be interpreted like this:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func b() (hiddenVariable int) {
    i := 0
    for ; i < 4; i++ {
        defer func() { fmt.Println(i); i++ }()
    }
    hiddenVariable = i; return // implicit meaning of return i
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("result = ", b())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based solely on what I learned about defer and after looking at your code, I'd like to say that the for loop defers the print out of subsequent 'i's until later, however, the for loop still runs and therefore affects the 'i' returned by 
func b(), which is 4.

```
for ; i < 4; i++ {
    defer func() {fmt.Println(i); i++} ()
}
return i
```

Because the print statement and it's 'value' for 'i' is deferred, they increment beyond 4, but the 'i' after the for loop remains at 4.

Answer (score 0):

`A defer statement pushes a function call onto a list. The list of saved calls is executed after the surrounding function returns.` Your **func b()** is semantically equivalent to:

```
func b() int {
    i := 0
    for ; i < 4; i++ {
    }
    ret := i
    fmt.Println(i); i++
    fmt.Println(i); i++
    fmt.Println(i); i++
    fmt.Println(i); i++
    return ret
}
```

Ergo b() returns 4.